# JWKS changes after IIS restart

Tags: iis, openid, openiddict

We are using OpenIddict, we have added Encription Certificate and Signing Certificate. The issue we have it is when the IIS restart the keys on /well-known/jwks changed, and other projects if not restart again have the wrong jwks keys, then throws 401 unauthorized. It is possible to use a fixed keys in /.well-known/jwks when the server restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you add the signing certificate? Where is it stored outside IIS?

If you use AddSigningCredential(...) and make sure the signing certificate is the same, then the JWKS keys should not change.

Comment: We are using options.AddSigningCertificate, the certificate it is a self signed certificate like openiddict documentation said. We are storing the certificate exported to an xml file and save it crypt with DPAP(Windows data protection api) to read the certificate we decrypt the certificate and import the private keys to X509Certificate2. Both for signing and encryption certificates

Comment: You are sure you don' use AddDeveloperSigningCredential somewhere? Also, do compare the details of your signing key/certificate on disk and the one in the JWKS,  are you sure the one you get in your JWKS is actually the same as on disk?

Comment: Yes, sure I'm not using AddDeveloperSigningCredential we are using options.AddSigningCertificate on local machine works fine, if I save it like a byte array, but for production server not working but this is another issue I think

Comment: The issue it is read this certificate that was created on the target machine, it is not readed by the target machine.. it says: WindowsCryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct. I added this: new X509Certificate2(unProtectedData,"", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet); But not changes same error

Comment: perhaps set a password when you generate it and use the same password when you read it? However the " The specified network password" error perhaps is a file system error? Is your cert on a network drive ? and not the local disk?

Comment: Sovled changing the applicationpool user to localSystem

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue
1 -export the Certificat like a byte array
2 -use DPAPI to encrypt the byte array
3 - save encrypted byte array into a file
Then the certificate can be restored fine and the jwks doesn't change after restart